# Active directory AD B2C android native msal fail to connect with AD

Tags: java, android-studio, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

when running the sample android app provided on MS site
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal , it seems to work as expected but when i replace the configs with my Azure AD B2C, I keep on getting Fail to parse JSON error.

what i have done:
1- create azure ad b2c
2- link it to a subscription (as suggested by MS)
3- created a resource group to contain it
4- created a native android app (the sample provided by azure--link above)
5- register the native app to the azure ad b2c
6- update the config in constant.java
7- update the android:scheme

when i run it, i end up with the Fail to parse Json. Im thinking this error might be a result of how my ad is set up but im not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e34sa.png)

Comment: Have you created [a sign-up or sign-in (or similar) user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows)?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Yes i have. I forgot to include that in the list of things ive done. I think it might have to do with the reply/redirect urls. I currently have: com.onmicrosoft.fabrikambb2c.{myTenantName}://oauthredirect